# React Router v6 prevent rerendering components around Routes using <Outlet />

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to create a fully protected React application. Only `Login` page should be available without login. However it has a completely different layout than rest of the application.

I am using simply `<Outlet />` for rendering the app layout. However on route change, the `Menu` and `Header` are also rerendering. Is there a solution how to prevent the rerender of these components?

App

```
const App = () => {
    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" index={true} element={<LoginRoute />} />

            <Route element={<ProtectedRoutes />}>
                <Route path="dashboard" index={true} element={<Dashboard />} />
                <Route path="article" element={<ArticleRoute />} />
                <Route path="article/add" element={<ArticleAddRoute />} />
                <Route path="article/:id" element={<ArticleEditRoute />} />
            </Route>

            <Route path="*" element={<ErrorPage />} />
        </Routes>
    );
};
```

ProtectedRoutes

```
const ProtectedRoutes = () => {
    const { userData } = useAuth();
    const location = useLocation();

    return userData ? (
        <Container>
            <NavContainer>
                <Menu />
            </NavContainer>
            <Main>
                <Header />
                <div>
                    <Outlet />
                </div>
            </Main>
        </Container>
    ) : (
        <Navigate to="/" state={{ from: location, status: 'unauthorized' }} replace />
    );
};
```

Should I separate the `LoginRoute` component completely out of the `Routes` and showing it conditionally if `userData` exists or is there any other solution?

Comment: What's wrong with them rerendering?

Comment: @Konrad I mean, they should be rendered only once if their content is not changing. Meaning Menu and Header f.e.

Comment: Components are likely rerendering because their parent component rerendered. Is there a problem with the header and menu rerendering? How exactly are you verifying/validating their renders?

Comment: @Drew Reese When I am navigating through protected routes (/dashboard, /article etc.) then components <Menu /> or <Header /> are rerendered every time I change the route. That's why I am looking for solution how to render only content of each route (meaning <Outlet />), not the Menu, Header etc.

In Menu and Header component I have console.log() at the very top of React.FC

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that really, React rerenders components when it needs to. You also never answered how you are verifying what is actually rerendering. If you are just console logging as an unintentional side-effect in the function body, well, this isn't an accurate measure of when the component is rendered ***to the DOM***. Place your logs in a `useEffect` hook so you see 1 side-effect per every app render to the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that they are rerendering because you use `useLocation`

```
const ProtectedRoutes = () => {
  const { userData } = useAuth();
  const location = useLocation();

  return userData ? (
    <TopBar />
  ) : (
    <Navigate
      to="/"
      state={{ from: location, status: "unauthorized" }}
      replace
    />
  );
};

const TopBar = () => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <NavContainer>
        <Menu />
      </NavContainer>
      <Main>
        <Header />
        <div>
          <Outlet />
        </div>
      </Main>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about the `Menu` and `Header` being possibly rerendered along with the `ProtectedRoutes` when the routes change, then I'd suggest separating them out into another layout component so their rerendering is decoupled from `ProtectedRoutes` component rerenders.

Example:

```
const AppLayout = () => (
  <Container>
    <NavContainer>
      <Menu />
    </NavContainer>
    <Main>
      <Header />
      <div>
        <Outlet />
      </div>
    </Main>
  </Container>
);
```

```
const ProtectedRoutes = () => {
  const { userData } = useAuth();
  const location = useLocation();

  return userData
    ? <Outlet />
    : (
      <Navigate
        to="/"
        state={{ from: location, status: 'unauthorized' }}
        replace
      />
    );
};
```

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<LoginRoute />} />

      <Route element={<AppLayout />}>
        <Route element={<ProtectedRoutes />}>
          <Route path="dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
          <Route path="article" element={<ArticleRoute />} />
          <Route path="article/add" element={<ArticleAddRoute />} />
          <Route path="article/:id" element={<ArticleEditRoute />} />
        </Route>
      </Route>

      <Route path="*" element={<ErrorPage />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};
```